# Use JWT with uuid lumen

Tags: laravel-5, jwt, lumen

I am using jwt in luman and use primary key `UUID` hexadecimal.

And firstly i got issues to Authenticate token by passing in header the issue was -

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from user` where users.id = 0 limit 1) "

but i solved it using `" protected $primaryKey = 'uuid'; "` put in model it fine.

But after i got another issue in **'jwt->attemp' it always give my UUID '30'** in numeric number when i login but when i remove the code form model it's working fine. Please help me about this issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/jwt.php` change:

```
'identifier' => 'id'
```

To

```
'identifier' => 'uuid'
```

Comment: yes i am using 'identifier' => 'uuid' but same issues.